# Applying the Mean Value Theorem to a Natural Log Function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

After my prof's lecture I came away unsure when I can and cannot apply the Mean Value Theorem. More specifically when the domain of $f'$ extends beyond the domain of $f$ (like in the case of a function using a natural $\ln$).

In the case of $f(x)= \ln(x+6)$, on interval $[3,8]$ the domain would be $x>-6$ or $(-6,∞)$.

-This would satisfy the 1st hypothesis since closed interval $[3,8]$ falls within the domain of $f$, $(-6,∞)$ and therefore $f$ would be continuous on $[3,8]$.

-But when I take the derivative, $f'(x)= 1/x+6$, the domain of $f'$ is $(-∞,-6)U(-6,∞)$

My question then is: since the domain of $f'$ extends beyond $f$, does this not satisfy the 2nd hypothesis for MVT on the given interval $[3,8]$?

Comment: Inasmuch as $f(x)=\log(x+6)$, $x\in (-6,\infty)$, its derivative is $f'(x)=\frac1{x+6}$, $x\in(-6,\infty)$.

While the function $f'(x)=\frac1{x+6}$ has a domain $(-\infty, -6)\,\cup\,(-6\infty)$, it does not represent the derivative of $f(x)=\log(x+6)$ over $(-\infty, -6)$ since $f$ is not defined on that open interval.  The MVT applies on closed intervals that are subsets of the domain of $f$ here.

Answer (score 1):

The domain here is not a problem.

You need to be carefull here, the domain of $f'(x)= 1/x+6$ is not  $f'$ is $(-∞,-6)U(-6,∞)$. The dom of $f'$ is $(3,8)$ on the interval $[3, 8]$

You can't evaluate $f'(x)= 1/x+6$ at $x=2$ since, from the definition of derivative:

$f'(2)= \lim_{\Delta x \to 0} \dfrac{f(2+\Delta x)-f(2)}{\Delta x}$ and $f(2)$ is not  defined because $2\notin dom(f)$.

I hope this help!